# python 2.7: Getting Segmentation fault when setting Menu in GUI programming with Tkinter

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, tkinter

I'm getting a segmentation fault everytime i want to run this code :

```
from Tkinter import *
def gui():  
        root=Tk()
        menubar=Menu(root)
        filemenu=Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label='New',command=gui)
        filemenu.add_command(label='Close',command=root.quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label='File',menu=filemenu)
        helpmenu=Menu(menubar,tearoff=1)
        helpmenu.add_separator()
        helpmenu.add_command(label="Help")#ajouter commande
        helpmenu.add_command(label='About...')#ajouter commande
        helpmenu.add_cascade(label='Help',menu=helpmenu)
        root.mainloop()

gui()
```

Any suggestion ? 
What should i do ? 
Thank you in advance. 
MFF

Comment: In which OS you are running. I just ran your example code it went just fine.

Comment: I just ran it in python 2.7.2 on mac osx Lion and got a seg fault as well.  So probably OS X.

Comment: Works fine on Ubuntu 11.10, with Python 2.7.2.  How long does it take for the segfault to come up?  What OS are you using?

Comment: Indeed, i'm using mac os x 10.6 :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The segfault is caused by:

```
helpmenu.add_cascade(label='Help',menu=helpmenu)
```

after a quick look at the docs, it makes perfect sense why that would give you problems.  Add cascade "adds a hierarchical menu item". You are adding helpmenu as a menu within helpmenu.

I believe that what you mean here is

```
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you ! ;) I was facing this for a while !